# Random Numbers in R and C++

Tags: c++, r, random

Say I want to generate a vector of 10 random numbers. How would I be able to do so in R and c++ such that I get the same vector?

I know in C++ I gotta use srand() and then rand()
while in R I can use set.seed() and then runif.

But how would I get them to be the same?

Comment: "I know in C++ I gotta use srand() and then rand()" - not if you want high quality random numbers...

Comment: For C++11, you should look at `<random>` instead of `std::rand`.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

Answer (score 12):

If you use the C API to R -- or, better still, the Rcpp interface for C++ built on top of it -- then you get **easy access** to the **same** streams from the same generators.

```
R> library(Rcpp)    # load Rcpp
R> cppFunction("NumericVector myrnorm(int n) { return rnorm(n); }")
R> # now we have a C++ function access n N(0,1) numbers
R> set.seed(41); myrnorm(3)
[1] -0.794368  0.197258  1.001704
R> 
R> # same thing in R
R> set.seed(41)
R> rnorm(3)
[1] -0.794368  0.197258  1.001704
R>
```

You note that they are both generate the same numbers given the same seed.  That **is a feature**.

Now, you could also bring your own RNG generator to R from C++ code. I do that eg in the [RcppZiggurat package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppziggurat) which [is also on CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppZiggurat/index.html).

Comment: I believe this is what I want. How would I implement this?

Comment: I just showed you. For the rest, and *many more example* see the Rcpp documentation.

Comment: Can I go the other way? I have a R code that is set, but I need to replicate in c++. So how would I write lbirary(Rcpp) in c++

Comment: Two choices: [RInside](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside), or using the [Rmathlib](https://packages.debian.org/sid/r-mathlib) library optionally buildable from R source with a subset of functions but including RNGs.

Comment: How would I be able to implment this within c++. I am not allowed to alter the R code.

Comment: Five month old post suddenly receives first down voted without comment. Very mature.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Does this slow down the C++ function in any way? From an optimization point of view, is this good practice? Is it better to include random numbers as an argument from an outside R call if we do not need to generate the numbers in the C++ function?

Answer (score 3):

Few things, I'm not sure if you are trying to build a stand alone application or just interface C++ code with R.

If it is the later, just use `Rcpp`'s wrappers into the list of `r` supported distributions.

e.g.

`R::runif(0.0,1.0)` or use sugar `Rcpp::runif(10, 0.0, 1.0)`

If it is the prior, check out [sitmo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sitmo/index.html) and how you can implement your own [runif](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sitmo/vignettes/uniform_rng_with_sitmo.html).

Comment: Why the downvote?  The answer says pretty the same thing as mine, without the example. We wrote them essentially at the same time.

Answer (score -5):

The whole idea of a random number generator is that the outcome is not predictable  or reproducible. If you expect the same output from two separate systems, e.g. implemented in R and C++, is relying on undocumented weaknesses of the implementations.

Incomprehensible why you would try this.

You want "a" vector. Assuming this means "one", why not save some numbers in a TXT file and have both the R and C++ app read from that file?

I would not rely on any predictable outcome of a random number generator. There is no guarantee that two C++ programming environments both calling RAND or RND or whichever library function will get the same numbers, let alone R and C++ apps. They might call different versions of RAND ...

Comment: well my aim is to try and replicate an r project in c++, but the r project has randomness in its implementation

Comment: OK, just follow Dirk's answer: use your own (random) number generator code in both languages. Randomness is not essential in your problem, so replace that by Determinism

Comment: @jenesaisquoi You are getting philosophical. I always believed you should use a 'random' seed to avoid starting at the predictable begin of a pseudo(=not) random sequence. The seed could be derived e.g. from a time stamp.